# PostgreSQL crosstab transpose row to column

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

Hi guys im trying to transpose a row query result to 1 row per columns

1st query is **select * from sku;**
the result is :

```
id sku  sku_code travel_code     
1   sku1    1   1
2   sku1    2   2
3   sku1    3   3
4   sku1    4   4
5   sku1    5   5
6   sku1    6   6
7   sku1    7   7
8   sku2    8   8
9   sku2    9   9
10  sku2    10  10
11  sku2    11  11
12  sku2    12  12
13  sku2    13  13
14  sku2    14  14
15  sku3    15  15
16  sku3    16  16
17  sku3    17  17
18  sku3    18  18
19  sku3    19  19
20  sku3    20  21
21  sku3    21  21
```

expected output is

```
SKU   SKU_CODE           TRAVEL_CODE  
sku1  1  2  3   4  5  6  7  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
sku2  8  9  10 11 12 13  14  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
sku3  15 16 17 18 19 20  21 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

no header is ok

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grouping` with `min` and `max` aggregation functions

```
with tab(sku, sku_cod, travel_code) as
(
 select 'sku1',109,'01' union all 
 select 'sku2',209,'02' union all
 select 'sku2',309,'03' union all
 select 'sku1',409,'04'   
)
select sku, min(sku_cod) as sku_cod1, max(sku_cod) as sku_cod2, 
            min(travel_code) as travel_code1, max(travel_code) as travel_code2
  from tab
 group by sku
 order by sku;

sku     sku_cod1    sku_cod2    travel_code1    travel_code2
sku1    109         409         01              04
sku2    209         309         02              03
```

Comment: how can i use the with tab if the select ... is came from the result of select * from ... query

Comment: @JakeGarbo I don't understand what you wanna say.

Comment: i cannot apply the 'sku1', 'sku2' statically because the query has dynamic skus

Comment: @JakeGarbo you need to share the whole requirement and sample input/output then.

Comment: @JakeGarbo do you need three columns `sku`, `sku_code` and `travel_code`, and concatenated integers as columns ?

Comment: hmm i dont get your point .. but i need to make it to be 1 column per value

Answer (score 0):

You are using Postgres, so I would recommend storing the values as arrays:

```
select sku, array_agg(sku_cod) as sku_cods
       array_agg(travel_code) as travel_codes
from t
group by sku
order by sku;
```

This will allow you to handle more than two values.